ERROR: new row for relation "membre_spec" violates check constraint "membre_spec_qualite_check"
ERROR: new row for relation "membre_spec" violates check constraint "membre_spec_qualite_check"
Detail: Failing row contains (4, 2024-04-12, 2024-04-15, 5, Co_Signature, Co_gerant1, 1, null).
I Check the conditions of the member_spec_qualite_check constraint in my database and its correct

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
